# Null Pointer exception while creating new Array list

Tags: java

I am getting null pointer exception in few cases while creating new array list.

`List<String> csvFileList = new ArrayList<String>();`

exception stack trace is showing above line . Want to know is there any chance of throwing null pointer exception in the above line ?

Comment: No It shouldn't.... show your stack trace instead

Comment: Can you please add StackTrace ?

Comment: There is no issue in above line. please provide your complete code, error is some where else.

Comment: The one line of code that you have provided can never generate a Null Pointer Exception. The exception lies in some other line which you have not yet provided to us. Show your code. Null pointer Exception comes up when you are trying to call a member of an object which is not yet initialised or is set to null

Comment: there was no type associated with the the list. It should be **List<type> listName=new ArrayList<type>();** Refer to this documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: If stack trace shows THIS LINE -> clean your project / recompile project / restart debugger.

Answer (score 2):

> Want to know is there any chance of throwing null pointer exception in the above line ?

No, I dont think that  it will ever throw NPE, Below line just `creating/instantiating` an List object so it wont throw null pointer exception in below line.

List csvFileList = new ArrayList();

Comment: Glad this got worked out re this being an answer or not. It does seem like an answer to me; perhaps not complete, but definitely related.

Answer (score 0):

You must be referring to the items of object, csvFileList which can cause null pointer exception. Stack trace is leading to the initialization of it, suggest to post the related code.

Comment: Thanks every one for replying